# Sum of squared differences

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write a function `SSD` that takes two **m** *x* **1** vectors and calculates the sum of squared differences.

I'm testing my SSD function with the vectors:

```
a = [0.5, -0.2, 1.7]';
b = [0.2, 0.9, 0.45]';
```

and I'm expecting the answer `2.862500`, but the result I get is `0.947500`

My function is as follows:

```
function [ z ] = SSD( a, b )

        z = sum( a(:,1) - b(:,1).^ 2 );
end
```

Am I right in thinking that `Z = sum( (Ai - Bi).^ 2 )` is the correct way to calculate the sum of squared differences? If so, why is my function not working correctly?

Comment: `z = sum( (a(:,1) - b(:,1)).^ 2 );`?

Comment: or `z = sum( (a - b).^2 )`

Comment: Some alternatives: `norm(a-b)^2`, `pdist2(a(:).',b(:).')^2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [**distributive property in mathematics**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) you forgot the brackets.
I shortened your code a little with `(:)` - which creates a column vector in any case, this way you don't need to care about the orientation of your input vectors.:

```
z = sum( (a(:) - b(:)).^2 )
```

If you have the **Neural Network Toolbox** you can also do:

```
z = sumsqr( a(:) - b(:) )
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, can't believe I forgot something so simple!